# how to set margin equal to another margin?

Tags: css

I have multiple inputs that is horizontally centered in a div.
I did this by

```
.inputs {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

How do I set the bottom margin of each input equal to the margin of the left/right?

Comment: Could you. Put some example code up. In particular are all the inputs the same width, and do you specifically require margin in the CSS sense or are you just wanting a gap between two input elements that is the same as the gaps at the side?

Answer (score -1):

> Remember this **"you can't add top or bottom margin to inline
> element"**

read more about the [block and inline](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) elements

also  **you cant make the top and the bottom margin auto**

**solution**

either you can hard code all margins

```
.inputs {
      display:block;
      margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

or you can hardcode the margin separately

```
.inputs {
    display:block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

you can also use the CSS variable

```
.inputs {
    display:block;
    --input-margin: 10px;
    margin-top:  var(--input-margin);
    margin-right:  var(--input-margin);
    margin-bottom:  var(--input-margin);
    margin-left:  var(--input-margin);
}
```